# Privacy in Google Cloud Platform vs Cloudkit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloudkit, google-drive-realtime-api

In Apple's iCloud, there's a Private bucket where the user can store data, using an iOS app created by a third party, that no one else, including the iOS app creator, can see.

Is there a similar mechanism in Google Cloud Platform? [image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming that you intend to read and write this private storage directly from a client app.

If you're using Firebase Authentication to sign in the user on the client, you can use either Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore to store per-user private information.  These products do not have an internal sense of dedicated storage for users.  What you will have to do is assign that space on your own (perhaps a "users" node in RTDB, or a collection in Firestore), and protect that space with the security rules provided by that database product.  The security rules will determine who can read and write what data, based on their Auth identity.

Since you tagged this Firestore, I'll assume you intend to use that.  You should read up on [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to better understand how this works.  If you are not using Firebase Auth for end user authentication, this will not be possible, however.